# Newly added Redmine route, view and controller returns 403 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm new to Redmine and Rails, and I have a question I'm stuck with.

I have a timelogger plugin installed from https://github.com/speedy32129/time_logger and it has a redirect option to the IssuesController edit method in Redmine source
https://github.com/speedy32129/time_logger/blob/master/app/controllers/time_loggers_controller.rb#L82

I want to create a custom controller action called edit_realtime, define a route for this and a custom view because I need to do some changes to this view and don't affect the original edit view.

What I've done:

1. Changed the `edit` method to `edit_realtime` in `app/controllers/time_loggers_controller.rb`:

```
        redirect_to controller: 'issues',
                    protocol: Setting.protocol,
                    action: 'edit_realtime',
                    id: issue_id,
                    time_entry: { hours: hours }
      end
```

2. Created a new controller method in `app/controllers/issues_controller.rb`

```
def edit_realtime
     return unless update_issue_from_params

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html {}
       format.js
     end
   end
```

3. Created a route in `routes.rb`

```
 post '/issues/new', :to => 'issues#new'
 get '/issues/:id/edit_realtime', :to => 'issues#edit_realtime'
```

4. Created the needed views in app/views/issue

```
edit_realtime.html.erb
edit_realtime.js.erb
_edit_realtime.html.erb
```

The result: 403 error when stopping the time log

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ksKI.png)

full route: http://localhost:81/redmine/issues/1/edit_realtime?time_entry%5Bhours%5D=0.0

and production log

```
Started GET "/redmine/time_loggers/stop" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-08-11 16:26:22 +0300
Processing by TimeLoggersController#stop as HTML
  Current user: alisa (id=1)
Redirected to http://localhost:81/redmine/issues/1/edit_realtime?time_entry%5Bhours%5D=0.0
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 14.8ms)
Started GET "/redmine/issues/1/edit_realtime?time_entry%5Bhours%5D=0.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-08-11 16:26:22 +0300
Processing by IssuesController#edit_realtime as HTML
  Parameters: {"time_entry"=>{"hours"=>"0.0"}, "id"=>"1"}
  Current user: alisa (id=1)
  Rendering common/error.html.erb within layouts/base
  Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.5ms)
  Rendered plugins/time_logger/app/views/time_loggers/_embed_menu.html.erb (6.6ms)
  Rendered plugins/time_logger/app/views/time_loggers/_update_menu.html.erb (8.5ms) [cache hit]
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected
Completed 403 Forbidden in 44ms (Views: 26.3ms | ActiveRecord: 13.1ms)
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: You should put that method in proper controller (Issues controller) ...

Comment: I haven't touched Redmine for a long time but I suppose you need to set permission for this action for your user's role.